# cant save multiple tables in cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I am learning cakephp and have made quite a bit already. The only reason I am asking this question  is that the docs in cakePHP could be wrong.
 I cant see from the docs or past stackoverflow posts on this issue why  the (child)Teacher table doesnt save the user_id from the id table in the (parent)User table.
I get no error but the user_id is 0 in the Teacher table so it isnt picking it up from the User table.
I have a one-one relationship on the 2 models.
I am just testing saving over 2 models where I have a User and teacher. I simply enter data in a form and create a new User and also a new teacher with the user_id being a foreign key in the teacher table.
I am loathe to ask this question as there is a lot of material on this but I just cant see my issue after following the docs in cakePHP.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html

```
    public function addteacher() {
   if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->User->create();

        }
      if (!empty($this->request->data)) {
        // We can save the User data:
        // it should be in $this->request->data['User']

        $user = $this->User->save($this->request->data);

        // If the user was saved, Now we add this information to the data
        // and save the Profile.

        if (!empty($user)) {
            // The ID of the newly created user has been set
            // as $this->User->id.
            $this->request->data['teacher']['user_id'] = $this->User->id; //here is the problem

            // Because our User hasOne Profile, we can access
            // the Profile model through the User model:
             if ($this->User->Teacher->save($this->request->data))
             {
                 $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your post has been saved.'));
                  return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'login'));  

             }
        }
      }


    }
  <?php
  echo $this->Form->create('User');

 echo $this->Form->input('User.username');
 echo $this->Form->input('User.password');


 echo $this->Form->input('Teacher.firstname');   //text
echo $this->Form->input('Teacher.surname');  
echo $this->Form->input('Teacher.address');   //text
echo $this->Form->input('Teacher.suburb'); 
echo $this->Form->input('Teacher.phone');
```

echo $this->Form->end('Save Post');
?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$this->request->data['teacher']['user_id'] = $this->User->id;`

should be

`$this->request->data['Teacher']['user_id'] = $this->User->id;`.

Capital "T". Model names are always CamelCased.

That said there is no need for 2 saves. You can just use

`$this->User->saveAll($this->request->data);`.

It will save both the User record and Teacher record adding proper foreign key value for the Teacher record (assuming you have setup proper association between User and Teacher model).

Comment: Thanks this it works but is there any benefit with saveAll over 2 saves?

Comment: Lesser code to write, atomic saves (i.e. with transaction).